# Finding the eigenvalues of a matrix problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

So I do know how to compute the eigenvalues of a matrix. At least, that's what I thought. I got the matrix

A = 
\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&0\\-2&0&2\\0&2&-1\end{bmatrix}

My approach is by finding the determinant:
\begin{equation}
    \text{det}\left(A-\lambda In\right) = 0
  \end{equation}

so it becomes
$$
\text{det}\left(
\begin{bmatrix}1-\lambda&-2&0\\-2&0&2\\0&2&-1-\lambda\end{bmatrix}
\right) = 0.
$$
But this gave me 8 lambda

According to calculators, it should give me -3, 3 and 0
What did I miss?

Comment: In position 2,2 there should be $-\lambda$ and not $0$.

Comment: I knew it was a stupid mistake. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Probably You have some othe mistake in the calculus of determinat.

Hint:

$$
\text{det}\left(
\begin{bmatrix}1-\lambda&-2&0\\-2&-\lambda&2\\0&2&-1-\lambda\end{bmatrix}
\right) = 
$$
$$
(1-\lambda) 
\text{det}\left(
\begin{bmatrix}-\lambda&2\\2&-1-\lambda\end{bmatrix}
\right) +2
\text{det}\left(
\begin{bmatrix}-2&2\\0&-1-\lambda\end{bmatrix}
\right)=
$$
$$
=(1-\lambda)(\lambda + \lambda^2-4)+2(2+\lambda)
$$
......